# new gui window not opening in eclipse

Tags: java, swing

I can't understand why the access history window is not opening for me, below is the code that is being executed and when I press the btnAccessHistory button nothing happens but it is giving me an error in the line **accessHistory gui=new accessHistory** and I can tell why.

```
package securitySystem;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class adminMenu extends JFrame{

public static void main (String args[]){
    //adminMenu gui= new adminMenu ();
    //gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //gui.setTitle("Admin Menu");

}       


JButton btnManageUsers= new JButton("Manage Users");
JButton btnAccessHistory= new JButton("Access History");

public adminMenu (String name){
    setLayout (null);
    setTitle("Amin Area");
    JLabel lblWelcome= new JLabel ("Welcome to the Admin Area " + name);


    lblWelcome.setBounds(100,0,300,30);
    add(lblWelcome);


    btnManageUsers.setBounds(120,70, 150, 30);
    add(btnManageUsers);


    btnAccessHistory.setBounds(120,130, 150, 30);
    add(btnAccessHistory);
}

public void calcButtons()
{
    btnAccessHistory.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            accessHistory gui =new accessHistory();
            gui.setSize (360, 450);
            gui.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            gui.setVisible(true);
            dispose();              
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: where is your accessHistory type??

Comment: its fine I figured it out, I had a parameter in my accessHistory window and didn't even realise! sorry for wasting your time